# Wallis' formula for pi

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
def wallis(n):
    pi = 0.0

    for i in range(n):
        left = (2 * i)/(2 * i - 1)
        right = (2 * i)/(2 * i + 1)
        total = left * right
        pi = pi + total

    return pi

print wallis(1000)
print wallis(10000)
print wallis(100000)
```

I copied the formula exactly but I keep getting 0 as the output. Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong. Python 2.7.

The link to the formula is [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wallis_product)

Comment: In Python 2.7, 2/3 is integer quotient, thus 0. You have to do float(2)/3, or 2/float(3), so that at least one operand is a float, to get a float quotient. Beware: in Python 3, 2/3 is the float result, you need to write 2//3 to get the integer quotient.

Comment: No need to calculate. According to [Indiana Pi bill](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indiana_Pi_Bill) it's 3.2. And it's O(1) to compute!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Python is doing integer division, and truncates the decimals.  This is because both values to division are integers.  Convert one of the numbers to a float to get a floating point value in return.

```
left = float(2 * i)/(2 * i - 1)
right = float(2 * i)/(2 * i + 1)
```

OR, as @kindall points out, you can change the constants to floats directly and avoid the call to the `float` function:

```
left = (2.0 * i)/(2 * i - 1) # just 2. works, too
right = (2.0 * i)/(2 * i + 1)
```

---

If/when you switch to python 3.x, you won't need to do this.  In fact, you need to explicitly request integer division with `//`.

As per a comment by @Serdalis, you could also add `from __future__ import division` at the top of your file to get the same behavior as python 3.x (i.e. you won't need to add the `float` in your equation.)

Comment: So I have to typecast the problem so to speak... I'm used to C and just learning Python. I am doing something mathematically wrong with my program. I can figure that part out. Thanks a lot.

Comment: IIRC the `//` integer division operator is available in Python 2.7 (even without the `from __future__`), and should probably be used when you really want integer. Reasons - to be more explicit, and better prepared for Python 3.x. It pains me to say that, though - I still think it was crazy to change the semantics of an arithmetic operator.

Comment: @juice No prob.  In C terms, I suppose this is like typecasting.  This is only necessary in python when doing division with two integers, and only in python 2.x.

Comment: You've got plenty of constants in those expressions, just change one of the `2`s to `2.0` in each and you won't need the `float()`

Answer (score 4):

Apart from problem highlighted by @SethMMorton your formula is wrong. First it is a product not sum, second it gives pi/2 not pi. At last there is no reason to loop from 0.

```
def wallis(n):
    pi = 2.
    for i in xrange(1, n):
        left = (2. * i)/(2. * i - 1.)
        right = (2. * i)/(2. * i + 1.)
        pi = pi * left * right
    return pi
```

Answer (score 2):

Just to add that you can do this in a pythonic way that also looks a lot closer to the mathematical expression. (Here the .25 takes care of the floating point conversion)

```
def product(iterator):
    return reduce(lambda x, y: x * y, iterator)

print 2 * product(i * i / (i * i - .25) for i in xrange(1, 1000))
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the Wallis formula:

[image]

...and with implementation in Python 3.4.2 with total execution time of `~0.095s` for `n = 100000`:

```
def wallis(n):
    pi = 0.0   
    for i in range(1, n):
        x = 4 * (i ** 2)
        y = x - 1
        z = float(x) / float(y)
        if (i == 1):
            pi = z
        else:
            pi *= z
    pi *= 2
    return pi

print(wallis(100000))
```

Comment: Code-only answers are discouraged.  It would be better if you included a brief explanation for why/how this works.

Answer (score 0):

Yet another solution, using list Built-in  functions and list comprehension for maximum "pythonicness" :)

```
2 * reduce(lambda x, y: x*y, [(4.0*(i**2))/(4.0*(i**2)-1) for i in range (1, 1000000)])
```

Answer (score 0):

The formula used as Wallis is wrong.The formula is
4 * productory from 1 to n of (2*i * (2i+1)) / (2*i+1)*(2*i+1).
With 1000 iterations I found
3.1423781499034176
But using Newton´s method with just 10 iterations I found
3.141592653589793
for those who don´t remember, the Newton´s method uses derivatives and the formula is (of course it must be used the command import math)
x-= f(x)/derivative_f(x)
where x is the initial value for the root (I used x=1)
and defined
def f(x):
return = math.tan(x/4)-1
def sec(x):  # the secant does not belong to math library
return 1/math.cos(x)
def derivative_f:
return (1/4)*sec(x/4)*sec(x)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: It reffers to pi calculus using the Wallis formula which was used in a wrong way

Answer (score -2):

```
pi = 2
count = 0
    while True:
        count = count + 1
        tcount = count * 2
        pi = pi * (((tcount) / ((tcount) - 1)) * ((tcount) / (tcount + 1)))
        print(pi, count)
```